# Convert string from UTF-8 to Windows-1256 in DB2

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, db2, ibm-data-studio

I want to convert `'my string'` in `CALL UTL_FILE.PUT(v_filehandle, 'my string');` from UTF-8 to Windows-1256. I use IBM data studio v4.1.2.

- I tried `EBCDIC_STR('my string')`. It didn't work, and this error appeared:

  > No authorized routine named "EBCDIC_STR" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.
- I also tried `CAST('my string' AS CLOB CCSID EBCDIC)` and the program didn't accept EBCDIC.

Comment: `CCSID` 420 or 425 or 1256? Cf. [Coded character set identifiers](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/ccsid/ccsid_registered.html)

Comment: I already have tried CAST('my string' AS CLOB CCSID 1256), but it doesn't work.

Comment: I found this function in Oracle which convert from any encoding to another
SELECT CONVERT('my string', 'UTF8', 'AR8MSWIN1256') 
   FROM DUAL;                                                                                                    I want same query in DB2